# Script to check if vim is open or another script is running?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm making a background script that requires a user to input a certain string (a function) to continue. The script runs fine, but will interrupt anything else that is open in vim or any script that is running. Is there a way I can test in my script if the command line is waiting for input to avoid interrupting something?

I'm running the script enclosed in parenthesis to hide the job completion message, so I'm using (. nightFall &)

Here is the script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
# nightFall
clear
text=""
echo "Night begins to fall... Now might be a good time to rest."
while [[ "$text" != "rest" ]]
do
 read -p "" text
done
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you launch nightFall from the shell you are monitoring, you can use "ps" with the parent PID to see how many processes are launched by the shell as well:

```
# bg.sh
for k in `seq 1 15`; do
    N=$(ps -ef | grep -sw $PPID | grep -v $$ | wc -l)
    (( N -= 2 ))
    [ "$N" -eq 0 ] && echo "At prompt"
    [ "$N" -ne 0 ] && echo "Child processes: $N"
    sleep 1
done
```

Note that I subtract 2 from N: one for the shell process itself and one for the bg.sh script. The remainder is = how many other child processes does the shell have.
Launch the above script from a shell in background:

```
bash bg.sh &
```

Then start any command (for example "sleep 15") and it will detect if you are at the prompt or in a command.